Pandas Boolean Conditioning
If i have a boolean pandas column, how can i make every True value to be followed by at least 2 False values? Is it possible to make the 2 into a variable so that i can adjust this to be any integer? I also need this to be done using a vectorization approach.
For example, if i have df['bool_col'] = [False, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, False] and a variable that is set to 2, i would like to create another column that is df['new_col'] = [False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False]. Thus, wherever there is a True value, it is followed by at least 2 False values.
I think i also need to assume that the last N rows need to be False. so if the variable is 2 then assume the last 2 rows are False.

Your desired column ends with True, False, so you've already broken your own rule...

Please bring the change by editing your own post, not in a comment. Please also try the code formatting between back ticks

I wonder if rolling window (with size 3) could help.

unfortunately not

Try this:
s = pd.Series([False, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, False])

(s.where(
    s.rolling(4,1).agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1] if x.iloc[0] or not any(x.iloc[:-1]) else False).astype(bool),False)
    .tolist())

Output:
[False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False]


This is the closest answer I have seen so far. The only problem is it seems to break down if there is a different order of True and False, especially when there are a number of True's together.

can you update your example to show these cases?

there is no specific example because the boolean column is randomly set by another function so it could spit out any combination of True and False. What i am trying to do is come up with a way to set the minimum number of False rows after the True row. This value can be any integer from 1 to 10. The main issue seems to arise when there are a number of successive True's. If there are more than 3 Trues in a row it seems to mess things up.
